# Как сделать аналогичный XMLHttpRequest fetch запрос?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yii2, postman

Подскажите в чём разница, половину вечера сижу смотрю...

На сервере (фреймворк Yii2) есть такой код.

```
 public function actionCreateImages()
    {

        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $images = new Images();
        $images->scenario = Images::SCENARIO_CREATE;
        $images->attributes = \Yii::$app->request->post();

        if($images->validate()){
            $images->save();
            return array('status'=>true, 'data'=>'images created successfully');
        } else {
            return array('status'=>false, 'data'=>$images->getErrors());
        }
    }
```

В PostMan запрос правильно обрабатывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код запроса из Postman

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("name", "test");
data.append("file", "test");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://advanced/admin/api/images/create-images");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "9cf730e3-d78b-41a0-8c76-a0075fd5e714");

xhr.send(data);
```

Я использую на ноде fetch запрос следующего вида.

```
async function post (obj) {
  var data = new FormData()
  data.append('name', 'test')
  data.append('file', 'test')
  fetch(`http://advanced/admin/api/images/create-images`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    },
    body: data
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function (json) {
    console.log('################### response ###################')
    if (json.status === 404) {
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~~ 404 ~~~~~~~~~~', json)
      return json
    } else {
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~~ object ~~~~~~~~~~', json)
      return json
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.assert(false, '~~~~~~~~~~ error ~~~~~~~~~~', error)
  })
}
```

У меня в response выдаёт status false

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём отличие от POST запроса из PostMan ?
Почему у меня не получается передать данные ?

Comment: Скорее всего csrf  мешает. Его можно отключить в контроллере. А вообще дебажить надо.